# Two versions of one button in various screen sizes, when using Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I had to use two CSS styles for one HTML div in various Bootstrap 3 screen sizes. Example:

```
<div class="p5Small hidden-xs hidden-sm col-md-12">button</div>

<div class="p5 col-xs-12 hide-sm-12 hidden-md hidden-lg">button</div>

.p5Small{                    /*p5 nesting in HEADING for small screen*/
    margin-top:170px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    font-size: 24px; 
    text-align: center;
    background-color:#968A9B;
    float: left;    
    height: 70px;
    color: white;
    line-height: 70px;
}

.p5{                    
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    font-size: 24px; 
    text-align: center;
    background-color:#968A9B;
    float: left;    
    height: 70px;
    color: white;
    line-height: 70px;
```

I know, it is bullshit, but I have no idea yet how to make it more properly. Thank in advance for suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the **media screen**. The browser will change the style automatically once the screen resized. You don't need to make 2 button and 2 different styles:

HTML :

```
<div class="p5 col-xs-12">button</div>
```

CSS:

```
.p5{                    
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    font-size: 24px; 
    text-align: center;
    background-color:#968A9B;
    float: left;    
    height: 70px;
    color: white;
    line-height: 70px;
}

@media screen and (max-width:768px){
    .p5{
        margin-top:170px;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks mate, you saved probably hours of my investigation :D I noticed that @media does something, but was not sure how to do it :)